# Is it possible to detect position (footer, sidebar) of HTML element when parsing document?

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, dom

I'm trying to develop a script (in php) that anlayzes web pages and wondering if it's possible to detect the position of an image or a link on a page, whether it's located on the a) top/bottom of the page or b) on the left/right side and whether top half/bottom half of the page. I was wondering if there's any accurate method of parsing the HTML and detecting accurately the position of these elements as they would be displayed on the page.

Comment: @Dagon Is there already an existing solution available to identify position of element when parsing, then if so, could you point me in the right direction...sorry if I'm missing something obvious out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fool prove method. Cos different browsers will render differently on different screens. This is a procedure best suited to using javascript running on the client browser.

What is the reason you need the position on the servers for?

A few ways to implement it (off the top of my head)...

1) Spawn IE or firefox (or any browser) in the background, to get the location using javascript that will then pass it to the php scripts?

2) Download and compile the website library and write a php module (plugin) to handle this?

3) Have the position be calculated in javascript on the client end, and use AJAX to pass the position back to the server?

4) Redo the web page, so that we don need to care about the position?

Comment: If Javascript is the only reliable way then what method would you recommend at being able to automatically emulating a browser and running javascript to extract the data, is there any such possibility? I would want the script to run automatically on my server without having to rely on my physical browser for the data, so is there any way to do so automatically server-side of emulating a browser

Comment: Well, javascript runs in the browser, after the page has been rendered, so it will be able to get the positions. However you will need to take into consideration different browsers that your clients will be using, cos different browser renders stuff differently. (famously IE7....)

Comment: Depends on the server you are running. If it is windows and you want to use IE, just spawn IE from PHP and get it to render the page, then get the position. If you want to use chrome or safari, you can look into using the webkit.net library andwriting a program in .net to get the position

Comment: If it is linux, you might need to investigate on how some of the browsers can be automated. Cos in windows you have OLE and ActiveXs but I am not so sure about linux.

Comment: Thank you, will do some research to figure it out, the server rus on linux so need to find out how to automate the process using this OS

Comment: Well, if you want do do the programming in C, I think you can use webkit and compile it into your program. But it looks difficult.